# How to avoid conflict of two scheduled jobs

Tags: cron, mule, scheduler

I have one scheduled cron job (at the momment) runs every 5 minutes, the process looks for messages into database (oracle) with status "error" and then it gets all elements to continue in determinate flow (I am working with Mulesoft's Mule Runtime), I think if the process runs in two or more nodes it will reprocess two or more times, because the first node can get 10 registers and the second node also can get the same 10 registers and both of two process will send the same elements two times.

Is there a way to avoid this functionality? What is the best practice in this cases? Should I find another solution?

Please help me with this.

Comment: I have achieved the same solution using IS_ACKNOWLEDGED flag. By default set to N and when acknowledged by your first_job, set it to Y. So it didn't get picked up next time due to having flag as Y.

Comment: @ErgiNushi, How will you stop having the same rows twice?

Comment: @AnkitBajpai I've missed the reprocessing part. Deleting.

Comment: You need to provide more details. Which version of Mule Runtime? Add a snippet of the XML scheduler or poll element. Are you deploying the application to multiple independent on prem nodes, a cluster, or on CloudHub?